Problem with Angular 17 Reactive form using Angular Materials
I'm a beginner who's trying to build a Reactive Form in Angular 17 (standalone components) using Angular Materials. For the moment, I have a parent component called 'ReservationComponent' in which I call the child component called 'FormInputComponent'.
This is the parent component .TS :
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import {
  FormBuilder,
  Validators,
  ReactiveFormsModule,
  FormControl,
  FormGroup,
} from '@angular/forms';
import { CommonModule } from '@angular/common';

// COMPONENTS
import { FormInputComponent } from '../../shared/form-input/form-input.component';
import { TimeInputComponent } from '../../shared/time-input/time-input.component';
import { DateInputComponent } from '../../shared/date-input/date-input.component';
import { PrefixInputComponent } from '../../shared/prefix-input/prefix-input.component';

// MODULES
import { TranslateModule } from '@ngx-translate/core';
import { NgbAlertModule, NgbDatepickerModule, NgbDropdownModule } from '@ng-bootstrap/ng-bootstrap';

// FONT AWESOME
import { FaIconComponent } from '@fortawesome/angular-fontawesome';
import {
  faUser,
  faEnvelope,
  faUsers,
  faMobile,
  faMapPin,
  faEuroSign,
  faExclamationCircle,
  faCircleXmark,
  faCalendarDays,
  faEuro,
} from '@fortawesome/free-solid-svg-icons';

// Angular Materials
import { MatInputModule } from '@angular/material/input';
import { MatFormFieldModule } from '@angular/material/form-field';
import { MatStepperModule } from '@angular/material/stepper';
import { MatButtonModule } from '@angular/material/button';
import { ErrorStateMatcher } from '@angular/material/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-reservation',
  standalone: true,
  imports: [
    ReactiveFormsModule,
    FaIconComponent,
    CommonModule,
    NgbAlertModule,
    NgbDatepickerModule,
    NgbDropdownModule,
    TranslateModule,
    FormInputComponent,
    TimeInputComponent,
    DateInputComponent,
    PrefixInputComponent,
    MatButtonModule,
    MatStepperModule,
    MatFormFieldModule,
    MatInputModule,
  ],
  templateUrl: './reservation.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./reservation.component.css'],
})
export class ReservationComponent implements OnInit {
  // REACTIVE FORM
  firstFormGroup!: FormGroup;
  secondFormGroup!: FormGroup;
  thirdFormGroup!: FormGroup;

  isLinear = true;

  constructor(private _formBuilder: FormBuilder) {}

  ngOnInit(): void {
    this.firstFormGroup = this._formBuilder.group({
      firstName: [
        '',
        {
          validators: [
            Validators.required,
            Validators.minLength(2),
            Validators.maxLength(50),
            Validators.pattern('^[A-Za-zÀ-ÖØ-öø-ÿ\\s]+$'),
          ],
        },
      ],
      lastName: [
        '',
        Validators.required,
        Validators.minLength(2),
        Validators.maxLength(50),
        Validators.pattern('^[A-Za-zÀ-ÖØ-öø-ÿ\\s]+$'),
      ],
      email: [
        '',
        Validators.required,
        Validators.minLength(5),
        Validators.maxLength(254),
        Validators.pattern('^[a-zA-Z0-9._%+-]+@[a-zA-Z0-9.-]+\\.[a-zA-Z]{2,}$'),
        Validators.pattern('^[^\\s]+$'),
      ],
      phoneNumber: [
        '',
        Validators.required,
        Validators.minLength(10),
        Validators.maxLength(20),
        Validators.pattern(/^\+\d{1,3} \d{6,14}$/),
      ],
    });

    this.secondFormGroup = this._formBuilder.group({
      name: ['', Validators.required, Validators.pattern(/^[A-Za-z\s]+$/)],
      creditCard: [
        '',
        Validators.required,
        Validators.minLength(16),
        Validators.maxLength(16),
        Validators.pattern(/^\d+$/),
      ],
      cvc: [
        '',
        Validators.required,
        Validators.minLength(3),
        Validators.maxLength(4),
        Validators.pattern(/^\d+$/),
      ],
      expirationDate: [
        '',
        Validators.required,
        Validators.pattern(/^(0[1-9]|1[0-2])\/\d{2}$/),
      ],
      billingAddress: ['', Validators.required],
    });

    this.thirdFormGroup = this._formBuilder.group({
      numberOfPeople: ['', Validators.required, Validators.pattern(/^\d+$/)],
      date: ['', Validators.required],
      time: ['', Validators.required],
    });
  }

  // First step form controls (initialize here)
  get firstNameControl() {
    return this.firstFormGroup?.get('firstName') as FormControl;
  }

  get lastNameControl() {
    return this.firstFormGroup?.get('lastName') as FormControl;
  }

  get emailControl() {
    return this.firstFormGroup?.get('email') as FormControl;
  }

  get phoneNumberControl() {
    return this.firstFormGroup?.get('phoneNumber') as FormControl;
  }


  get isFormValid(): boolean {
    return this.firstFormGroup.valid
  }


  faExclamationCircle = faExclamationCircle;
  faEuroSign = faEuroSign;
  faMapPin = faMapPin;
}

and this is its HTML:
<mat-stepper orientation="vertical" [linear]="isLinear" #stepper>
        <mat-step [stepControl]="firstFormGroup">
          <form [formGroup]="firstFormGroup">
            <ng-template matStepLabel>{{ "reservation.steps.one" | translate }}</ng-template>
              <app-form-input
              [formControl]="firstNameControl"
              label="reservation.labels.firstName"
              placeholder="reservation.placeholders.firstName"
              requiredError="reservation.errors.firstName.required"
              minLengthError="reservation.errors.firstName.minLength"
              maxLengthError="reservation.errors.firstName.maxLength"
              patternError="reservation.errors.firstName.pattern"
              ></app-form-input>
              <app-form-input
              [formControl]="lastNameControl"
              label="reservation.labels.lastName"
              placeholder="reservation.placeholders.lastName"
              requiredError="reservation.errors.lastName.required"
              minLengthError="reservation.errors.lastName.minLength"
              maxLengthError="reservation.errors.lastName.maxLength"
              patternError="reservation.errors.lastName.pattern"
              ></app-form-input>
              <app-form-input
              [formControl]="emailControl"
              label="reservation.labels.email"
              placeholder="reservation.placeholders.email"
              requiredError="reservation.errors.email.required"
              minLengthError="reservation.errors.email.minLength"
              maxLengthError="reservation.errors.email.maxLength"
              patternError="reservation.errors.email.pattern"
              ></app-form-input>
              <app-form-input
              [formControl]="phoneNumberControl"
              label="reservation.labels.phoneNumber"
              placeholder="reservation.placeholders.phoneNumber"
              requiredError="reservation.errors.phoneNumber.required"
              minLengthError="reservation.errors.phoneNumber.minLength"
              maxLengthError="reservation.errors.phoneNumber.maxLength"
              patternError="reservation.errors.phoneNumber.pattern"
              ></app-form-input>
            <div>
              <button mat-button matStepperNext [disabled]="!isFormValid">Next</button>
            </div>
          </form>
        </mat-step>
        <mat-step [stepControl]="secondFormGroup">
          <form [formGroup]="secondFormGroup">
            <ng-template matStepLabel>{{ "reservation.steps.two" | translate }}</ng-template>
            <mat-form-field>
              <mat-label>Address</mat-label>
              <input matInput formControlName="secondCtrl" placeholder="Ex. 1 Main St, New York, NY"
                     required>
            </mat-form-field>
            <div>
              <button mat-button matStepperPrevious>Back</button>
              <button mat-button matStepperNext>Next</button>
            </div>
          </form>
        </mat-step>
        <mat-step [stepControl]="secondFormGroup">
          <form [formGroup]="secondFormGroup">
            <ng-template matStepLabel>{{ "reservation.steps.three" | translate }}</ng-template>
              <mat-label>Address</mat-label>
              <input matInput formControlName="secondCtrl" placeholder="Ex. 1 Main St, New York, NY"
                     required>
            <div>
              <button mat-button matStepperPrevious>Back</button>
              <button mat-button matStepperNext>Next</button>
            </div>
          </form>
        </mat-step>
        <mat-step>
          <ng-template matStepLabel>{{ "reservation.steps.confirmation" | translate }}</ng-template>
          <p>You are now done.</p>
          <div>
            <button mat-button matStepperPrevious>Back</button>
            <button mat-button (click)="stepper.reset()">Reset</button>
          </div>
        </mat-step>
      </mat-stepper>

This is the child component .TS:
// NG
import { Component, Input } from '@angular/core';

// FORM CONTROLS
import {
  FormControl,
  FormsModule,
  ReactiveFormsModule,
} from '@angular/forms';

// FONT-AWESOME
import { FaIconComponent } from '@fortawesome/angular-fontawesome';
import { faCircleXmark } from '@fortawesome/free-solid-svg-icons';

// MODULES
import { CommonModule } from '@angular/common';
import { TranslateModule } from '@ngx-translate/core';
import { MatInputModule } from '@angular/material/input';
import { MatFormFieldModule } from '@angular/material/form-field';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-form-input',
  standalone: true,
  imports: [
    FaIconComponent,
    TranslateModule,
    CommonModule,
    FormsModule,
    ReactiveFormsModule,
    MatFormFieldModule,
    MatInputModule,
  ],
  templateUrl: './form-input.component.html',
  styleUrl: './form-input.component.css',
})
export class FormInputComponent {
  @Input() formControl!: FormControl;
  @Input() label!: string;
  @Input() inputType!: string;
  @Input() placeholder!: string;
  @Input() requiredError!: string;
  @Input() minLengthError!: string;
  @Input() maxLengthError!: string;
  @Input() patternError!: string;
}

and this is the HTML:
<form class="example-form" >
  <mat-form-field class="example-full-width col-md-4">
    <mat-label>{{ label | translate }}</mat-label>
    <input [type]="inputType" matInput [formControl]="formControl" [placeholder]="placeholder | translate">
    <mat-error *ngIf="formControl?.hasError('required')">
      {{ requiredError | translate }}
    </mat-error>
    <mat-error *ngIf="formControl?.hasError('minlength')">
      {{ minLengthError | translate }}
    </mat-error>
    <mat-error *ngIf="formControl?.hasError('maxlength')">
      {{ maxLengthError | translate }}
    </mat-error>
    <mat-error *ngIf="formControl?.hasError('pattern')">
      {{ patternError | translate }}
    </mat-error>
  </mat-form-field>
</form>

I can see all the errors (and the specific errors also), but the button 'Next' stays disabled, always. I do not know how to resolve it, or more generally, what is the best practice for building this form.
I also feel like I'm repeating myself somehow. How can I build this in the best way?
